# Bouncing an element into view with jquery

Tags: jquery

I am making a simple portfolio site and I would like to have a series of elements, `<divs>` I suppose bounce into view when their thumbnail buttons are clicked.

I want it to look something like this: http://plugins.jquery.com/project/Bounce

Where the item starts at a location with a negative left position to be hidden off screen and then slides/bounces into place for viewing.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

http://gsgd.co.uk/sandbox/jquery/easing/

you can use this plugin.